# How do I fix the errors in this code (Triangle class in Python)?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to test my triangle class, especially at the draw_triangle function but keep getting error: "unbound method forward() must be called with Turtle instance as first argument (got int instance instead)". How do I fix that?

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from math import sqrt, degrees, acos
import turtle


class Triangle():
    def __init__(self, a = None, b = None, c = None):
        self.a = a;
        self.b = b;
        self.c = c;

def is_triangle(self):
    s = 0.5 * (self.a + self.b + self.c)
    return (s - self.a) > 0 and (s - self.b) > 0 and (s - self.c) > 0

def perimeter(self):
    return self.a + self.b + self.c

def area(self):
    s = 0.5 * (self.a + self.b + self.c)
    return sqrt(s * (s - self.a) * (s - self.b) * (s - self.c))

def a_angle(self):
    return degrees(acos((self.b ** 2 + self.c ** 2 - self.a ** 2) / (2.0 * self.b * self.c)))

def b_angle(self):
    return degrees(acos((self.a ** 2 + self.c ** 2 - self.b ** 2) / (2.0 * self.a * self.c)))

def c_angle(self):
    return degrees(acos((self.a ** 2 + self.b ** 2 - self.c ** 2) / (2.0 * self.a * self.b)))

def angles(self):
    angA = a_angle(self)
    angB = b_angle(self)
    angC = c_angle(self)
    return angA, angB, angC

def __str__(self):
    return 'lengths =  %d, %d, %d' % (self.a, self.b, self.c) + \
           ', perimeter = %d' % (perimeter(self)) + \
           ', area = %d' % (area(self)) + ', angles = %d' % (angles(self))

def draw_triangle(self):
    window = turtle.Screen()
    t = turtle.Turtle
    t.forward(self.c)
    t.left(180 - a_angle(self))
    t.forward(self.a)
    t.left(180 - b_angle(self))
    t.forward(self.b)
    t.done()
    window.exitonclick()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    triangle1 = Triangle(100,100,72)
    triangle2 = Triangle(100,100,100*sqrt(2))
    triangle3 = Triangle(100,50,50)
    print (triangle1)
    print (triangle2)
    print (triangle3)
    Triangle.draw_triangle(triangle1)
    Triangle.draw_triangle(triangle2)
    Triangle.draw_triangle(triangle3)
    turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are bunch of indentation mistakes in your code; are they due to copying or actual code?

Comment: @ pseudoAJ this is my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from math import sqrt, degrees, acos
import turtle


class Triangle():
    def __init__(self, a = None, b = None, c = None):
        self.a = a;
        self.b = b;
        self.c = c;

    def is_triangle(self):
        s = 0.5 * (self.a + self.b + self.c)
        return (s - self.a) > 0 and (s - self.b) > 0 and (s - self.c) > 0

    def perimeter(self):
        return self.a + self.b + self.c

    def area(self):
        s = 0.5 * (self.a + self.b + self.c)
        return sqrt(s * (s - self.a) * (s - self.b) * (s - self.c))

    def a_angle(self):
        return degrees(acos((self.b ** 2 + self.c ** 2 - self.a ** 2) / (2.0 * self.b * self.c)))

    def b_angle(self):
        return degrees(acos((self.a ** 2 + self.c ** 2 - self.b ** 2) / (2.0 * self.a * self.c)))

    def c_angle(self):
        return degrees(acos((self.a ** 2 + self.b ** 2 - self.c ** 2) / (2.0 * self.a * self.b)))

    def angles(self):
        angA = self.a_angle()
        angB = self.b_angle()
        angC = self.c_angle()
        return angA, angB, angC

    def __str__(self):
        return 'lengths =  %d, %d, %d' % (self.a, self.b, self.c) + \
               ', perimeter = %d' % (self.perimeter()) + \
               ', area = %d' % (self.area()) + ', angles = %d %d %d' % (self.angles())

    def draw_triangle(self):
        window = turtle.Screen()
        t = turtle.Turtle
        t.forward(self.c)
        t.left(180 - self.a_angle(self))
        t.forward(self.a)
        t.left(180 - self.b_angle(self))
        t.forward(self.b)
        t.done()
        window.exitonclick()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    triangle1 = Triangle(100,100,72)
    triangle2 = Triangle(100,100,100*sqrt(2))
    triangle3 = Triangle(100,50,50)
    print (triangle1)
    print (triangle2)
    print (triangle3)
```

You need "self."  in front of method calls

Here is a slightly modified draw_triangle function.  It runs, but probably doesn't do exactly what you want.

```
    def draw_triangle(self):
        window = turtle.Screen()
        t = turtle.Turtle()
        t.forward(self.c)
        t.left(180 - self.a_angle())
        t.forward(self.a)
        t.left(180 - self.b_angle())
        t.forward(self.b)
        turtle.done()
        window.exitonclick()
```

I think you should work on it a bit by yourself now.

Comment: @Jean Chang, if this fixes your errors, can you please mark the answer as accepted, cheers.

Comment: how do I call the draw_triangle function?

Comment: Like this:

    triangle1.draw_triangle()

But the routine fails because in the 'forward' call, you need to give the distance to move forwards....  So you need to think about how far you want to move forwards with each call to 'forward'.